# How to use triconfluent Heun's function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, special-functions

When solving an eigenvalue problem, I encounter the [triconfluent Heun's function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HeunT.html), $HeunT[-\lambda^2,0,-2\alpha,0,-b^2](x)$, which is the solution of $$u''-(b^2x^2+2\alpha)u'+\lambda^2u=0.$$
I need a $u(x)$ not divergent at $\infty$ and this condition hopefully can give us the eigenvalue $\lambda$. (This is just like Legendre function can be cut off to Legendre polynomial.) However, I can't find any clear info about this as far as I've searched. Maybe I missed something.

The numerical eigensolution to the original problem is very well-behaved. So I presume there must be some condition like this to help find the eigenvalue.